# How to traverse VDOM when using m.component() in Mithril?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I´m new to Mithril, but very pleased about the way it enforces good coding patterns and the separation of concerns. Referring to this I started coding, making intensive use of m.component().

Later I read the Mithril-Article "When CSS lets you down" (http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/when-css-lets-you-down.html), which explains how to write Transformer-Functions to travers and manipulate the virtual DOM-Tree. A brilliant concept to write several kinds of cross-cutting-concerns.

But when I tried to use this pattern with a VDOM containing components, it doesn´t work because m.component is returning a component and not a VDOM-Object. Detecting the component doesn´t help, because the embedded view is not constructed at this point.

Now I´m asking myself, how to handle this issue or if I missunderstood something fundamentally wrong...

Here a few lines of code showing the Problem:

```
...

someComponent.view = function() {
return m('html', [
    m('body', [
        m('div', [
            m.component(anotherComponent)
        ])
    ])
};

...

// and now the traversal function from the mithril side
var highlightNegatives = function (root, parent) {
    if (!root) return root;
    else if (root instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
            highlightNegatives(root[i], parent);
        }
    } else if (root.children) {
        highlightNegatives(root.children, root);
    } else if (typeof child == "string" && child.indexOf("($") === 0) {
        parent.attrs.class = "text-danger";
    }
    return root;
};

highlightNegatives(someComponent.view()); // will not find the relevant elements in "anotherComponent"
```

How do others handle that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components were added after the blog post was written.

You need to convert a component into a vDOM object before you can include it in a view. Notice I've done this 2 times, once inside the highlightNegatives() function to catch components while we traverse the vDOM tree, and also in the function parameters when we call it in the view.

You can just include the component identifier without the call to m.component(), unless you want to send attributes or other options to the component:

```
myComponent
vs.
m.component( myComponent, {extraStuff: [1,2,3]}, otherStuff )
```

You'd need to consider this when calling highlightNegatives().

There's no need to include **html** and **body** in your templates. The browser does this for you (or you can include them in index.html, of course)

Here's a working example of the code below:
http://jsbin.com/poqemi/3/edit?js,output

```
var data = ['$10.00', '($20.00)', '$30.00', '($40.00)', '($50.00)']

var App = {
  view: function(ctrl, attrs) {
    return m("div.app", [
      m('h1', "My App"),
      someComponent
    ])
  }
}

var anotherComponent = {
  controller: function (){
    this.data = data
  },
  view: function (ctrl){
    return m('div.anotherComponent', [
      m('h3', 'anotherComponent'),
      ctrl.data.map( function(d) {
        return m('li', d)
      })
    ])
  }
}

var someComponent = {}
someComponent.controller = function (){ }
someComponent.view = function (ctrl) {
  return m('div.someComponent', [
      m('h2', 'someComponent'),
          highlightNegatives(anotherComponent.view( new anotherComponent.controller() ))
        ])
};

// and now the traversal function from the mithril side
var highlightNegatives = function (root, parent) {
    if (!root) return root;
    else if (root instanceof Array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {       
        // when you encounter a component, convert to VDOM object
        if (root[i].view) {
          highlightNegatives(root[i].view( new root[i].controller() ))
        }else{
          highlightNegatives(root[i], parent);
        }
      }
    } else if (root.children) {
        highlightNegatives(root.children, root);
    } else if (typeof root == "string" && root.indexOf("($") === 0) {
          parent.attrs.class = "text-danger";
    }
    return root;
};

m.mount(document.body, App)

//Calling this function after the App is mounted does nothing.
//It returns a vDOM object that must be injected into the someComponent.view
//highlightNegatives(someComponent.view()); // will not find the relevant elements in "anotherComponent"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this (helped me a lot in understanding the mithril components). But the problem with the component parameters still leads me to the point, where I can not generically traverse the hole VDOM, right?. In a bigger team setup, building components would be one of the biggest issues, and I guess you will result in very deep components structures. However, I think it is a very elegant way for cross-cutting some sub-trees...

Comment: Internally Mithril turns `m.component( MyComp, {opt: 42}, moreOpts )` into `{ controller: function( {opt: 42}, moreOpts ){ ... }, view: function( ctrl, {opt: 42}, moreOpts ){ ... } }` If I understand your concern correctly, you shouldn't have to worry about parameters since `m.component` injects them for you, per component.